# Maptip containing an expression combining a CASE WHEN-clause and a hyperlink consisting partly of value from table column

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

I am using maptips in QGIS 3.4, but the below expression won't work.

What I am trying to do is to use a `CASE WHEN`-clause in combination with a `HREF` from a webserver where the last part of the URL comes from the table column.

Here is my code:

```
 [%CASE WHEN "pdf_link3" IS NULL THEN 'No other documents' ELSE '<a href="http://geodocs/pdf/Lokalplan_oevr_dok/"pdf_link3">Click here</a>'
END %]
```

'pdf_link3' is a table column and contains the name of the pdf document, for instance 'lokalplan.pdf'.

Putting it like the above QGIS the `CASE WHEN` works, but the URL is loaded without the last part expected to be loaded from the attribute table.

Can anybody figure out how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know, how links in QGIS map tips work.

But when we're only talking about the field calculator syntax, the following show be correct:

```
[%CASE WHEN pdf_link3 IS NULL 
THEN 'No other documents' 
ELSE '<a href="http://geodocs/pdf/Lokalplan_oevr_dok/'||pdf_link3||'">Click here</a>' 
END %]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're adding several parts of text from different sources together, you need to use `||` (aka pipes) or `concatenate(...)` between/around the different parts.

Comment: Thank you :-). Do you know the syntax when it comes to QGIS actions? I actually have the same issues as with the maptip. I need the action to open a pdf in a browser using the prefix `http://geodocs/pdf/Lokalplan_oevr_dok/` and value from the attribute table `[%pdf_link3%]`, but it won't work...

Comment: @kwiwe have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html). Especially section 6.4.4 should help you.